# Почему steam не видет второй хард?

Tags: linux, archlinux

Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня 2 харда, но steam видит только один, что нужно сделать или под какую файловую систему оборудовать второй хард?

Comment: А как и куда у вас подключен и примонтирован второй хард?

Comment: Какая ОСь? Win или Linux?

Comment: @Andrew метки .

Comment: Стим виндовый или нативный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При установки стим из репозитория (`sudo pacman -S steam`) делаем так.

Зайди в программу Диски.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шестеренка - изменить параметры монтирования:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате добавится строчка в `/etc/fstab` :

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/546ade5a-fe9b-47ad-b468-a290d8ca2475 /mnt/data auto x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

которую, конечно, можно сформировать вручную и записать через `visudo` или другой текстовый редактор.

Потом отключить-подключить, возможно перезагрузиться и диск будет виден в стиме:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы как-то неосторожно подразумеваете, что некая программа «Диски» вообще установлена

Comment: это же арч, тут может не быть чего угодно: blkid, vi также могут не оказаться в системе с той же вероятностью)

Comment: @andreymal обновил ответ